# Integrating Accept.js with NextJs on TypeScript with 'npm react-authorize-net'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, accept.js

Hi I'm currently having an issue with integrating Accept.js
I'm using https://github.com/j-em/react-authorize-net#readme

```
  <FormContainer
      apiLoginId={`${process.env.PAYMENT_API_LOGIN_ID}`}
      clientKey={`${process.env.PAYMENT_API_LOGIN_CLIENT_KEY}`}
      onSuccess={(arg: any) => console.log(arg)}
      onError={(arg: any) => console.log(arg)}
      amount={99}
      component={FormComponent}
      environment={'sandbox'}
    />
```

And I'm getting: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

[image]

Thank you for helping

Comment: Seems like an issue with your webpack config/how that library is packaged. Their build outputs ES Modules but webpack seems to trying to load them as CommonJS modules. Webpack should handle that, make sure your all of your webpack and loaders are up to date.

Comment: well, currently my app does not have Webpack config, ill will config it and return with an update. Thank you for help

Comment: Make sure your are using the latest webpack!

Comment: Yep, it worked thank you

Comment: You mean updating webpack? What version were you running?